# Convert SQL Query into Laravel query

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am trying to check the given input is already existed between the c_start and c_end through query, but it is not working. Here is my controller.. for example if person 1 booked a room from 10 to 12 then person can't book the same room at same date from 11 to 12 or any time between the existing booked time.

```
/* namespace App\booking; */

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\booking;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use DB;
use App\Quotation;
use DateTime;

class RoombookController extends Controller {

    public function insert_check(Request $request) {

        $roomname = $request->input('roomname');
        $book = $request->input('bookdate');

        $dbstime = explode(':', $request->input('starttime'));
        $dbetime = explode(':', $request->input('endtime'));

        $dbstime[0] = $dbstime[0] * 60;
        $dbetime[0] = $dbetime[0] * 60;

        $dbsum = array_sum($dbstime);
        $dbesum = array_sum($dbetime);

        $users = DB::table("bookings")
                 ->select("id")
                 ->where('bookdate', '=', $request->input('bookdate'))
                 ->where('roomname', '=', $request->input('roomname'))
                 ->where(function ($query){
                           $query->where('c_start', '<', $dbsum);
                           $query->orWhere('c_end', '>', $dbsum);
                         })
                 ->orWhere(function($query){
                             $query->where('c_start', '<', $dbesum);
                             $query->orWhere('c_end', '>', $dbesum);
                           });
        if ($users->count() == 0) {
            $booking = new booking;
            $booking->bookdate = $request->input('bookdate');
            $booking->roomname = $request->input('roomname');
            $booking->starttime = $startTime = $request->input('starttime');
            $booking->endtime = $finishTime = $request->input('endtime');
            $booking->purpose = $request->input('Purpose');
            $booking->booked_by = Auth::user()->id;



            $smstime = explode(':', $startTime);
            $emstime = explode(':', $finishTime);


            $smstime[0] = $smstime[0] * 60;
            $emstime[0] = $emstime[0] * 60;

            $startsum = array_sum($smstime);
            $endsum = array_sum($emstime);


            $booking_time = $startTime . ' to ' . $finishTime;

            $booking->c_start = $startsum;
            $booking->c_end = $endsum;
            $booking->booking_time = $booking_time;

            $time = ($etime - $stime) / 60;
            $booking->total_duration = $time;

            $booking->save();

            return view("bookmessage");
        } else {
            return view("duplicateValue");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the query from which i got my correct result

```
 $whereCondition = array('bookdate'=>$request->input('bookdate'),'roomname'=>$request->input('roomname'));
    $users = DB::table("bookings") 
           ->select("id") 
           ->where('bookdate', '=', $request->get('bookdate')) 
           ->where('roomname', '=', $request->get('roomname'))
           ->whereRaw(DB::raw("((c_start<$dbsum and c_end>$dbsum) or (c_start<$dbesum and c_end>$dbesum ))"))
           ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code and let me know if it works:

```
   $whereCondition = array('bookdate'=>$request->input('bookdate'),'roomname'=>$request->input('roomname'));
$users = DB::table("bookings") 
               ->select("id") 
               ->where($whereCondition) 
               ->where(function ($query use $dbsum){
                   $query->where('c_start','<',$dbsum);
                   $query->orWhere('c_end','>',$dbsum);
               })
               ->orWhere(function($query use $dbesum){
                  $query->where('c_start','<',$dbesum);
                  $query->orWhere('c_end','>',$dbesum);
               })
               ->get();
```

Comment: Undefined variable: dbsum i don't know why this error is showing

Comment: was your query running fine because I have made few edits only. Please post what value you are getting as $dbsum

Comment: if i give input my start time as 10 then dbsum will be 10*60=600 and by dd() i get that value before the query but in query it is not finding

Comment: were you getting any errors before you changed the query and try both the variants

Comment: is there any other variable with same name in any other function on the same controller, also check for the line number in which the error is generated.

Comment: not there are no other function or controller which have this variable..and error is showing at this line  $query->where('c_start','<',$dbsum);

Comment: always showing my room is booked...no matter what i give input at start time and endtime

Comment: try logging query and post the result, to log query do the following:
`DB::enableQueryLog(); //before $whereCondition`
`dd(DB::getQueryLog()); // after $users query`

Comment: no it must show entire raw query if it is showing [] then the placement might be wrong

Comment: and after enabling logging queries it is showing this
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select `id` from `bookings` where (`bookdate` = ? and `roomname` = ?) and (`c_start` < ? or `c_end` > ?) or (`c_start` < ? or `c_end` > ?)"
    "bindings" => array:6 [▼
      0 => "2016-12-27"
      1 => "2"
      2 => 240
      3 => 240
      4 => 360
      5 => 360
    ]
    "time" => 2.0
  ]
]

Comment: the complete query you are getting is : `"select id from bookings where (bookdate = 2016-12-27 and roomname = 2) and (c_start < 240 or c_end > 240) or (c_start < 360 or c_end > 360)"`

Comment: yeah the above query i correct but why i am not getting the desired output then?

Comment: because the raw query you posted and the query you are getting is different

Comment: Raw query : 
`SELECT * FROM `bookings` WHERE `bookdate`='2016-12-27' AND `roomname`='3' AND (($dbsum>`c_start` AND $dbsum<`c_end`) OR ($dbesum>`c_start` AND $dbesum<`c_end`))`
new query :
`select id from bookings where (bookdate = 2016-12-27 and roomname = 2) and (c_start < 240 or c_end > 240) or (c_start < 360 or c_end > 360)`
See the difference after roomname

Comment: btw what was your raw query can you post it again so that i can explain you further

Comment: well for setting the query like this ($dbsum>c_start AND $dbsum<c_end) i need to do this ->where(function ($query) use ($dbsum){
                   $query->where($dbsum > 'c_start');
                   $query->orWhere($dbsum < 'c_end');
and here dbsum is not found..showing error

Comment: now try :
`$whereCondition = array('bookdate'=>$request->input('bookdate'),'roomname'=>$request->input('roomname'));
$users = DB::table("bookings") 
               ->select("id") 
               ->where($whereCondition) 
               ->whereRaw("AND (($dbsum>c_start AND $dbsum<c_end) OR ($dbesum>c_start AND $dbesum<c_end))")
               ->get();`

Comment: did u see my full controller code?? i am sending data to the db variable c_start through this $booking->c_start...so do in need to declare this in top or anywhere?? as i am calculating it below but want to use it up in the query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131586/discussion-between-incorporeal-and-rahul).

Answer (score 1):

Change query to:

```
$users = DB::table("bookings") 
            ->select("id") 
            ->where('bookdate', '=', $request->get('bookdate')) 
            ->where('roomname', '=', $request->get('roomname'))
            ->where(function ($query) use ($dbsum, $dbesum){
                $query->where(function ($query) use ($dbsum){
                    $query->where('c_start','<',$dbsum);
                    $query->Where('c_end','>',$dbsum);
                 })
                 ->orWhere(function($query) use($dbesum){
                    $query->where('c_start','<',$dbesum);
                    $query->orWhere('c_end','>',$dbesum);
                }); 
            });
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' this is showing..but i can't see any error like this here

Comment: my bad, i missed ; after  }). please check again.

Comment: always showing my room is booked...no matter what i give input at start time and endtime

Answer (score 0):

You can run your sql query directly in laravel query builder .You can try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `bookings` WHERE `bookdate`='2016-12-27' AND `roomname`='3' AND (($dbsum>`c_start` AND $dbsum<`c_end`) OR ($dbesum>`c_start` AND $dbesum<`c_end`))";

$result = DB::select(DB::raw($sql))
```

$result variable contains your output. You must be use your DB class

```
use DB;
```